# Eclipse refusing to launch Searching Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am studying searching algorithms and have made a program of my own, but it wont run, it says :

> The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches

here is the code:

```
 int[] b = {2, 6, 9, 10, 21, 23, 35, 40 };
 public int binS(int key) {
     int least = 0;
     int greatest = b.length - 1;
     while (least <= greatest) {
         int middle = (least + greatest) / 2;
         if (b[middle] == key)
             return middle;
         else if (b[middle] < key)
             least = middle + 1;
         else
             greatest = middle - 1;
         System.out.println(middle);
     }
     return -1;
 }
```

Thank you so much for the help,
Daniel

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I am new to Java.

Comment: Is that your whole Java file ? Where is your `main` function ?

Comment: yes, I am sorry if i'm missing something important, my course isn't as explicit

Comment: In order to run a Java program, you need a `public static` method called `main`. You can read more about [here](https://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html). That's probably why your function does not run.